# blacklight retribution point system

Tags: blacklight-retribution

My friend has played this game countless times and has had 20+ kills and the winner has had 10-15 kills. I dont get this. How does the point system work? If somebody could help out its would be greatly appreciated

Comment: what mode were you playing? the scoring changes depending on the mode.

Comment: Deathmatch not the team deathmatch

Answer (score 1):

BLR is (in most game modes) a team-based game, and the scoring reflects that. It is possible to get quite a high score without ever actually killing anyone by focusing on helping your team instead. Someone who made 20 kills but did nothing *but* kills is going to lag behind someone who made 15 kills, but who was also healing or reviving teammates, capturing objectives, repairing hardsuits, and suchlike.

Unfortunately I can't find a definitive source online for how the scoring works; the [Blacklight Wiki entry on Combat Points](http://blacklight.wikia.com/wiki/CP) is woefully incomplete. But based on my recollection from playing it, here is an *incomplete* list of actions that get you points:

- kills (bonuses for headshots and taking out enemy HVTs)
- assists (also counts debuffs, you don't necessarily have to damage them)
- healing friendlies
- reviving dead-but-not-yet-respawned friendlies
- hacking control points, or assisting in a hack
- recovering your team's flag
- grabbing or capturing the enemy flag
- repairing a friendly hardsuit
- opening gates for the friendly tank in Siege

In addition, there are point bonuses for killing sprees (large numbers of consecutive kills without dying).

So, if someone with a high kill count is getting routinely beaten at the scoreboard by someone with a lower kill count, it's because the second player is also spending time helping out their teammates and accomplishing team objectives, or because they are just better at killing and are making more headshots, picking more valuable targets, and getting more kills before dying -- or both.

Comment: Okay but how does the people that win have fewer kills and have more points than the higher kills but somehow lower points on deathmatch

Comment: @amp more headshots, killing high threats, and killing the warlord (first place), and killing your rival